# uploading large file from ios

Tags: php, ios

I am trying to upload a large file it causes me trouble.
When I use smaller files to upload it works fine.

Here is the code in IOS I am using:

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostFormat:ASIMultipartFormDataPostFormat];
[request setPostValue:key forKey:@"key"];
[request setData:fileData withFileName:fileName andContentType:contentType forKey:key];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setTimeOutSeconds:60000];
[request startSynchronous];

NSError *error = [request error];
if (!error)
{
    NSString *response = [request responseString];
    if (kShowLog)
        NSLog(@"%@", response);
    return [self objectWthString: response];
}
else
    if (kShowLog)
        NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
    return nil;
```

Here is the PHP code:

```
function microtime_float_string()
{
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
    return $sec . ($usec * 1000000);
}

$myTime = microtime_float_string();
srand(time());
$rand1 = rand();
srand($rand1);
$rand2 = rand();
$str = $myTime . $rand1 . $rand2 . '.aiff';

$arr = array();

$uploaddir = 'images/';      //Uploading to same directory as PHP file

//$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$file = $str;
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

if (!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']))
{
    $arr["error"] = "File Upload Failed is_uploaded_file";
}
else if ($_FILES['userfile']['size']> 10000000)     //Limiting image at 10000K
{
    $arr["error"] = "File Size too Large";
}
else if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) 
{
    $url = SITE_URL . $uploadfile;
    $arr["message"] = "ok";
    $arr["url"] = $url;
}
else
{
    $arr["error"] = "File Upload Failed";
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: How large a file are we talking? `DEFINE "large", "10gig";`? Plus, are you checking for errors?

Comment: What error is given? What does it do when you upload a large file?

Comment: Well considering you've limited the upload size to `10mb`, these aren't very large files at all..

Comment: @Fred-ii- I get this error File Upload Failed is_uploaded_file

Comment: @Ohgodwhy not sure what is going on. it works fine for around 1 MB file

Comment: How big is the file that you're trying to upload? Do you have any size limits on the form that you're using?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to get the real error. So again, how large is the file that you are wanting to upload that makes it stop? It might just be a setting for max upload size in your `php.ini` file. If you can't modify that file, you can override that in your PHP or `.htaccess`

Comment: @Fred-ii- how can I override the max upload size limit in my code without touching php.ini file?

Comment: See this Q&A on Stack http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size - be sure to read all of it.

Comment: @NaveedRafi So, any luck?

Comment: @Fred-ii- my audio recording is generating around 30 MB file from two 3 MB files :(

Answer (score 0):

php in OSX by default accepts *2 mb*.

We have to update the *php.ini* file in order to accept files with bigger size.

The file is found under */etc/*

edit the values of *upload_max_filesize* & *post_max_size* in php.ini

then restart it by running the following command

```
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```